# Why can't I @Autowired my service directly in my test and why do I need to @Autowired the repository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot application with  `Repository`(s).

I also use `@Service` and extend the `repository` in it.

When I try to @Autowired the service I have:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.api.core.service.CountryService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

It work fine if I `@Autowired` the repository.

My test must look like this :

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("core")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { UserManagementConfig.class, UserManagementServiceConfig.class })
@UserManagementTx
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class BlogPostContentImplTest {
    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;
    @Autowired
    private BlogPostContentRepository blogPostContentRepository;
    private BlogPostContentServiceImpl blogPostContentService;
    private BlogPostContent entity = new BlogPostContent();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        blogPostContentService = new BlogPostContentServiceImpl(blogPostContentRepository);
        List<Country> countryList = countryService.findAll(null);
        entity = new BlogPostContent();
        entity.setId(1L);
        entity.setDescription("test");
        entity.setCountry(countryList.get(0));
        blogPostContentService.insert(entity);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        blogPostContentService.delete(entity.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void findAll() throws Exception {
        assertThat(blogPostContentService.findAll(null).size()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }

}
```

This is how I configure the context :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
        UserManagementConfig.CONTEXT_CLASSPATH
})
public class UserManagementConfig {
    public static final String CONTEXT_CLASSPATH = "com.api.userManagement.config.context.**";
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
        UserManagementServiceConfig.CLASSPATH,
})
public class UserManagementServiceConfig {

    public static final String CLASSPATH = "com.api.userManagement.service.**";

}
```

Comment: annotate`CountryService` class with `@Component`?

Comment: @flakes it is a transactional `@Service` and `@Service` is also catched by `@ComponentScan` according to spring documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, it seems you might need to component scan the `com.api.core.service.CountryService` Bean in one of your test context classes `UserManagementConfig` or `UserManagementServiceConfig`

```
@ComponentScan({
     basePackages = {"com.api.core.service"}
})
```

---

To test if app context loads your beans, you can create a `TestContext` class like below

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.api.core.service")
public class TestContext implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestContext.class, args);
    }
}
```

Have `TestContext` configured in your test like below

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class})
```

Comment: Oh, this is because I am importing from another package I didn't pay intention, but it does the same thing if it's from the local package

Comment: Are you loading the application context in your test, your beans need to get initialized in order to autowire them?

Comment: I am not doing `SpringApplication.run()` anywhere, but some other `@Service` test are working fine without it

Comment: Are you sure they're not loading the app context through any base class?

Comment: They are same kind of test

Comment: How can I initialize the application quickly within my test to see ?

Comment: Added the quick snippet to test this

Comment: That still produce `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type`, I think something is wrong